# HTML table multiple data save in mysql data

Tags: php, html, mysqli

I have created php program to order food items. User has been given table. That html table has 4 columns `food item`,`quantity`,`price`,`order`. User can only give input to `order` column.

When user give inputs in HTML table and click order button it should be saved in MySQL order table. But I am not able to do that work successfully. I want to do this using only PHP. Without using JavaScript. Help me to solve this.

[image: HTML table interface]

HTML code

```
<form action="order2.php" method="POST">
    <table border="1">
        <tr>
            <th>Food Item</th>
            <th>Quantity available</th> 
            <th>Item Price</th>
            <th>Order</th>  
        </tr>
        <?php
        while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result1)) {
            ?>
            <tr>
                <td><?php echo $row['fitem']; ?></td>
                <td><?php echo $row['qty']; ?></td>
                <td><?php echo $row['price']; ?></td>
                <td><input type="text" name="order"></td>
            </tr>
            <?php
        }
        ?>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <input type="submit" value="order" align="right">
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</form>
```

php code

```
<?php
session_start();

$order = $_POST['order'];

$servername = "localhost";
$username = "root";
$password = "";
$dbname = "mid";

$conn = mysqli_connect($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);

if (!$conn) {
    die("Connection failed: " . mysqli_connect_error());
} else {
    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result1)) {
        $sql = "insert into order (fname,order) values('$row['fitem']',$order)";

        if (mysqli_query($conn, $sql)) {
            echo "New order created successfully";
        } else {
            echo mysqli_error($conn);
        }
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: I don't understand why you are using this  line `while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result1)) {` I can't see any value for $row or if you've fetch some data..

Comment: You need to assign a unique identifier for your order field so that you can correlate it to your products.

Comment: @ShadowFiend  can u give me a code solution as a answer.i am new to programming.

Comment: what are you trying to do? Why do you need to fetch some data?

Comment: @ShadowFiend ok i did it.but not success again.i want to save 4 columns at once.

Comment: what is the expected value of `$order`? what is the expected value of `$row['fitem']'`?

Comment: @ShadowFiend `$order` is the input value from user.`$row['fitem ']` is the food item taken from another sql table

Comment: @pleh_pro please update your question with all the missing data (from comments).